# How to get last text between two text?

Tags: flutter

> How I will find the last text between two or three  text

```
 I/p:
 String text='Hello Monkey';
 String text='Hello hi Monkey';


 op:
```

1. Monkey
2. Monkey

Comment: Your question doesn't seem clear to me. Can you explain it differently?

Comment: To get last string of multiple string separed by `space`, first `split` it into multiple strings with `space separator  ` and get the last item of returned list of string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with below lines [image]

```
    String text='Hello hi Monkey';
    print("Lst Word: ${text.substring(text.lastIndexOf(" "))}");
    print("First Word: ${text.split(" ")[0]}");
```

I hope this will work for you

Comment: @Spidertechsoft for first word you can use =>  text.split(" ")[0]

Answer (score 0):

```
String text='Hello Monkey';
List<String> words = text.split(" ");
print(words.last);
```